# Apache Spark running on YARN with fix allocation

Tags: apache-spark, resources, hadoop-yarn

What's happening right now is YARN simply gets a number of executor from one spark job and give it to another spark job. As a result, this spark job encounters error and die.

Is there a way or an existing configuration where a certain spark job running on YARN have a fix resource allocation?

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear. Can you update it with some code snippets, etc to make the context clearer. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Fix resource allocation is an old concept and doesn't give benefit of proper resource utilization. Dynamic resource allocation is an advanced/expected feature of YARN. So, I recommend that you see what is happening actually. If a job is already running on then YARN doesn't take the resources and gives it to others. If resources are not available then the 2nd job will get queued and resources will not be pulled up abruptly from the 1st job. The reason is containers have a combination of memory and CPU. If memory is allocated to other job then basically it means that the JVM of the 1st job is lost for ever. YARN doesn't do what have mentioned.